# Use custom 404 page for specific subdirectory only

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have Wordpress installed in the root of my server. I have a separate mobile version of the site in a subdirectory (No CMS just straight PHP which serves up content from the database).

When I encounter a 404 error in my subdirectory, the Wordpress 404 page comes up and I want it to use the custom one in the mobile directory.

Is there a way to do this easily. .htaccess manipulation possibly? It's currently got the standard Wordpress stuff at the moment.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file in your sub directory?

Answer (score 3):

What if you added an .htaccess file to your subdirectory root then put this as the top line.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/your404page
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is because of the way the WordPress rewrite system works. The WordPress .htaccess sends all requests (that dont actually exist except index.php) through the index.php file in the WordPress root directory. If any request is made for a file named index.php it will also get sent through the root WordPress index.php.

A simple solution would be to rename the index.php file in /subdirectory to default.php. Depending on your hosting setup it might work by just doing that. If it doesn't you can add a 301 redirect to your .htaccess that points www.domain.com/subdirectory to www.domain.com/subdirectory/default.php

```
Redirect 301 /subdirectory http://domain.com/subdirectory/default.php
```

The .htaccess file will be located in your public_html or root public web directory.

(from [#16584](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16584))